# Does d3.js force layout allow dynamic linkDistance?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm using the force layout to represent a directed unweighted network. My inspiration comes from the following example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292

[image]

My problem is that in my case there much more links between nodes and I have the feeling that giving a fixed linkDistance, which is always the same, is a very big constraint for my layout.

Is it possible to set a dynamic `linkDistance`, such that a link grows in length if it's useful to reduce link crossing inside the graph?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout):

> force.linkDistance([distance])
>
> If distance is specified, sets the target distance between linked nodes to the specified value. If distance is not specified, returns the layout's current link distance, which defaults to 20. If distance is a constant, then all links are the same distance. **Otherwise, if distance is a function, then the function is evaluated for each link (in order)**, being passed the link and its index, with the this context as the force layout; the function's return value is then used to set each link's distance. The function is evaluated whenever the layout starts. Typically, the distance is specified in pixels; however, the units are arbitrary relative to the layout's size.

Note that the link distance is still adjusted as the layout runs. You may also find setting `linkStrength()` useful.

Comment: So you mean that linkDistance is changing while the algorithm is running. I didn't know it. Do a linkStrength equal to 1 mean that the distance between nodes won't change?

Comment: No, the force layout will always adjust the distance (at least potentially) to satisfy the other constraints.

Comment: So what's the meaning of linkStrenght? I can't understand what's the "rigidity", also if I've noticed that a lower linkStrenght helps me a lot.

Comment: The strength is a multiplier applied to the distance.

Comment: Does this mean that if strength < 1 the distance can only decrease? What if strength > 1?

Comment: No, it's sort of a weight. You'll have to play around with the values to see what works for you.

Answer (score 7):

Just two steps:

Step1: Add a parameter in main json as follows:

{source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "licensing", value: 60},
  {source: "Microsoft", target: "HTC", type: "licensing",value: 60},
  {source: "Samsung", target: "Apple", type: "suit",value:60},

Step2: Update linkdistance to accept method.

```
.linkDistance(function(d) { return  d.value; })
```