# d3.js graph layout (force) centering root node

Tags: json, d3.js

I modified the les miserables code to implement what I am trying to do.  I want to have a graph, where there is one root node, and then only one level of nodes connected to that node.

As is, without trying to center the root node, it sort of works, but my text labels that were working, are generating errors.  The root node is positioned by default to the extreme upper left corner of the screen.  the child nodes are linked and floating to the middle of the screen.

1. I am trying to set the link distance based on an integer variable,
   but that does not seem to work.
2. The text labels for the nodes are not showing up (generating cx=NaN cy=NaN etc.. errors in the error log)
3. How do I center the root/source=0 node  without everything else breaking or disappearing?

I have the code (minus the json reading issue).  Please let me know if anyone has an tips. thanks.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.node {
  cursor: move;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node.fixed {
    fill: #f00;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>

<head>
    <title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">


//Size of region to render on
var width = 960,
    height = 500;


//D3 force directed layout
//Try playing with the charge and link distance
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-100)
    //.linkDistance(40)
    .linkDistance(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.distance);})
    //.on("tick", tick) //event ADDED
    .size([width, height]);

//Add our canvas
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


//Select the miserables data ;)
d3.json("nodes.json", function(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

//Add the links
  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      //.style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });
        .style("stroke-width", 2);

//Add the nodes
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .call(force.drag)
        .style("stroke-width", 4)
        .style("stroke", function(d) { if (d.M==1) {return d3.rgb(203,24,29)}
               else  {return d3.rgb(0,109,44)};})
        .style("fill", d3.rgb(246,232,195)); //});



 //add labels
  var labels = svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr({"x":function(d){return d.x;},
              "y":function(d){return d.y;}})

        .text(function(d) {
              if (d.name.length > 6) {return d.name.substring(0,6)+'...'}
              else    { return null } ;})
        .call(force.drag);


//Update stuff for animation:
//   This takes the physics simulation for the force directed graph and
//   sets the location of the nodes and edges to the new positions

force.on("tick", function(e) {

// soft-center the root node
         // soft-center the root node
//         var k = .01;
//         var nodes = force.nodes();
//         nodes[0].y += (height/2 - nodes[0].y) * k;
//         nodes[0].x += (width/2 - nodes[0].x) * k;
//nodes[0].fixed=true;
//           
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

    labels.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })        // **NEW**
           .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });



  });

});

</script>
```

nodes.Json

```
{
  "nodes":[

 {"name": "XXX.XXXX", "distance": 0, "M":0},
 {"name": "1", "distance": 0.2,  "M":0}, // I had .2, which did not read in, but adding a 0, & it works
 {"name": "2", "distance": 1.8,"M":0},
 {"name": "3", "distance": 4.5, "M":0},
 {"name": "4", "distance": 2.5,  "M":0},
 {"name": "5", "distance": 1,  "M":0},
 {"name": "6", "distance": 7,  "M":0},
 {"name": "7", "distance": 1,  "M":0},
 {"name": "8", "distance": 3,  "M":1},
 {"name": "9", "distance": 10,  "M":1},
 {"name": "10", "distance": 20,  "M":1},
 {"name": "11", "distance": 3,  "M":1},
 {"name": "12", "distance": 25,  "M":1},
 {"name": "13", "distance": 35,  "M":1}
],
"links":[

          {
          "source": 0,
          "target": 0
          },
          {
          "source": 0,
          "target": 1
          },
          {
          "source": 0,
          "target": 2
          },
          {
          "source": 0,
          "target": 3
          },
          {
          "source": 0,
          "target": 4
          },
          {
          "source": 0,
          "target": 5
          },
          {
          "source": 0,
          "target": 6
          },
          {
          "source": 0,
          "target": 7
          },
          {
          "source": 0,
          "target": 8
          },
          {
          "source": 0,
          "target": 9
          },
          {
          "source": 0,
          "target": 10
          },
          {
          "source": 0,
          "target": 11
          },
          {
          "source": 0,
          "target": 12
          },
          {
          "source": 0,
          "target": 13
          }
]
}
```

Comment: For centering the node, would [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843206/d3-force-layout-fix-root-node-at-the-center#21843473) help?

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes thank you for your reply.  When I add: `graph.nodes[0].x = width / 2;
graph.nodes[0].y = height / 2;` under `force.on("tick", function(e) {` (in my case I had to state graph.nodes because using nodes alone was not recognized) It does center the root node but then no other node is shown except one, and that node is placed in the upper extreme right hand corner.  when I remove these two lines, it goes back to showing the root node in the upper right hand corner, and plots the other nodes dangling in the center.  I am not sure why.

Comment: Your whole problem boils down to your `linkDistance` calculation: it is returning `NAN`, so all your coordinates are invalid. You will need to fix it. If you comment it out and simply use `.linkDistance(40)` then the graph renders fine with your root node at the center (without any special code to center it). See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsLqx/).

Comment: Thanks @FernOfTheAndes!! Now it is working. (I added `var nodes = force.nodes();` before accessing the `nodes[0].`)  Extra ?: Do you happen to know a way to change linkdistance based on a variable, for each node? Is there a better graph layout, besides force, to use for this?

Comment: `linkDistance` accepts a function, so as long as you return valid results from it, you have a chance of making it work. See this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567750/d3-js-force-layout-with-dynamic-linkdistance#16567906).

Comment: I tried `linkDistance` in `var force = d3.layout.force()
    //.linkStrength(function(a) { return ((a.value)+70);})`... and `d3.json("json/nodes.json", function(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      //.linkDistance(function(a) { return ((a.value)+70);})`..... and the `force.on("tick", function(e) {` but I am having an issue accessing the value and get the NAN issue. I am not sure why, I was able to access a.value when using `.sort(..` in d3.js tree.